# Existence of natural number $t$ such that none of the numbers $f_i(t)$ is a $p$-th power in $L$.

Tags: number-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L$ be an algebraic number field and $R$ be the ring of integers in $L$. Let
$f_l,...,f_m \in R[x]$, and assume that the leading coefficient of each $f_i$ is one, and that for
some prime number $p$, none of the $f_i$ s is a $p$-th power in $R[x]$. Then there exists a natural number $t$ such that none of the numbers $f_i(t)$ is a $p$-th power in $L$.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/224881/polynomials-which-always-assume-perfect-power-values . With some little tweaks it solves your problem.

Comment: Actually, I didn't get it. I am trying to prove only using basic kinds of stuff. It is possible for you to suggest any other so that I can understand.